# Modal inside a dropdown list is not working

Tags: html, css, list, modal-dialog, dropdown

I'm trying to put the link to my modal inside a drop down list.  this link here works fine.

```
 <li><a href="#openModal" id='rosterBtn'><span id=''class='playButtons     badge primary'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i></span>Add Players</a></li>
```

but once i put it inside my dropdown list here

```
<li class = 'has-submenu'>
      <a href="#">Roster</a>
          <ul class="submenu menu vertical">

          <li><a href="#openModal" id='rosterBtn'><span id=''class='playButtons badge primary'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i></span>Add Players</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

it stops working.

I'm using Foundation CSS framework.

Thanks for any input

Comment: add your code js fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/barrard/x59jsad9/1/

sorry took a while my internet is not working well at the moment.
and the code is a bit messy.

basically, click in the outside Add Players link and modal pops up.  But the nested list in the drop down "Add Players" doesnt show a modal

Comment: It will be better if the fiddle will actually works (don't put a `php` code there) not just showing the code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/barrard/x59jsad9/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/barrard/x59jsad9/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have change your html code `#openModal` to `#addPlayerModel`

```
<li><a href="#openModal" id='rosterBtn'><span id=''class='playButtons badge primary'><i class='fa fa-user-times'></i></span>Edit Players</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="#addPlayerModel" id='rosterBtn'><span id='' class='playButtons badge primary'><i class='fa fa-user-times'></i></span>Edit Players</a></li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x59jsad9/5/

Comment: Thank you for your fresh eyes to see my simple (stupid) mistake